# Mongoose return all documents that contain a value wherever inside a property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Lets say my documents look like this :

```
  _id: "6285e9a7aff93ead37ec50ad",
  date: "2022-04-28T10:51:37.923Z",
  devices: {
    tablets: [
      {
        brand: "samsung",
        model: "s20"
      },
      {
        brand: "samsung",
        model: "s21"
      },
      {
        brand: "apple",
        model: "ipad_mini"
      },
    ],
    phones: [
      {
        brand: "samsung",
        model: "galaxy_s20"
      },
      {
        brand: "samsung",
        model: "galaxy_s20_lite"
      }
    ],
    laptops: []
  }
}
```

how would i query and return all documents that contain at least an `"apple"` value in `"brand"` property **wherever** inside the `"devices"` property ?

Comment: Can `devices` have many categories, or only few?

Comment: @nimrodserok lets say 3,tablets,phones,and laptops

Comment: Then use ['$elemMatch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Comment: @nimrodserok like this : { devices: { $elemMatch: { "brand":"apple" } } }. ?

Comment: Like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fd0yV-zVMS4

Comment: @nimrodserok ahh,i see,is there a way to do the same query if i dont know the names or the amount of categories inside the devices property ?

Comment: Not the same query, but there is a way. I will answer

Comment: @Gibbs here, did it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have more dynamic keys, you can use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "d": {
        "$objectToArray": "$devices"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "d.v.brand": "apple"
    }
  }
])
```

You need to restructure the data if required. It returns if there is atleast one match.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tbkxd3nijL_)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "d": {
        "$objectToArray": "$devices"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "d.v.brand": "apple"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "devices": { //To reshape back
        "$arrayToObject": "$d"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VizyjoVhubM)

Comment: hey,thanks,do you know how i would also return the rest of the document ? for my example,"date" is not returned !

Comment: Instead `$project`, you could use `$addFields`.It will add an additional field rather than skipping other fields